# Google maps API - Center map on client's current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I've looked at the various other times this question has been asked but I can't quite put a finger on where I'm going wrong, here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Map </title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 500px;
        width: 800px;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize()
        {
            var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.65914, 0.072050);

            var mapOptions = 
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: myLatlng1,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);


            <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY ID DESC");
                while($row =mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    $desc = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
                    $location = $row['LOCATION'];
                    $counter += 1; 
                ?>

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location; ?>),
                map: map,
                title: '<?php echo $desc; ?>',
                icon: '/image/cam.png'
            });

           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);  
        }

        var showPosition = function (position) 
           {
               map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude), 16);

           }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
```

It originally sets the center to myLatlng1, and the code at the bottom to set it to the user's current location doesn't do anything, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/onury/geolocator  locates the user position and automatically creates a map with a centered marker.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try using the below code to get the user's current location (**GEOLOCATION**):

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
         initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
         map.setCenter(initialLocation);
     });
 }
```

For showing an example, I've removed your php code. Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xY8sB/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for your piece of code. Its really helped me

Comment: Your JSFiddle didn't work for me. I didn't get prompted to show my current location. Pages must be HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

To provide a useful map whether user allowed or denied the browser's "Allow location detection?" prompt (modify the default location to suit):

```
<script>
  function initMap() {

  gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // Center on user's current location if geolocation prompt allowed
    var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    gMap.setCenter(initialLocation);
    gMap.setZoom(13);
  }, function(positionError) {
    // User denied geolocation prompt - default to Chicago
    gMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.8097343, -98.5556199));
    gMap.setZoom(5);
  });
}
</script>
```